# Owl Carousel, last item on drag callback

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, owl-carousel

I have 6 items in my owl carousel that loads on init, where 3 is shown and the next 3 will show on clicking the next button.

Once i reach the end i have to click on next to load the next 3 via ajax.

```
Page 1 : on init (item 1, item 2, item 3)
Page 2 : on next/drag show (item 4, item 5, item 6)
on click next (item 7, item 8, item 9, item 10, item 11, item 12) loads
```

and the process above repeats itself.

What i would like to do is when i reach the end (Page 2) and drag:

```
Page 2 : on next/drag show (item 4, item 5, item 6)
```

I would like to load:

```
(item 7, item 8, item 9, item 10, item 11, item 12)
```

by dragging instead of clicking.

There is no callback and ive tried a few techniques but it doesnt work.

I know how to check(callback) when i view the next 3 items (Page 2), but letting the jQuery know that im dragging again is a bit of an issue.

Any ideas or help would be appreciated.

**Notes:** There is 10 000 items on the site, loading them all is not a possibility.